# Not able to group data according to month given in a date using SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following set of sample data from a database

```
Period      Company    Metric    Values
01/01/18       A        Vol       2
02/01/18       A        Vol       4
04/02/18       A        Vol       5
05/02/18       B        Vol       6
06/03/18       B        Vol       4
07/04/18       C        Vol       1
08/05/18       C        Vol       6
```

I wish to display a total of "Values" for each company according to month.
For Example 'company A' has a total value of 6 for first month and value of 5 for second month

As a first step, I tried working as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, `Period`) = 01;
```

But it is throwing an error and it also does not have a group by function

Can anyone please tell how it can be done

Comment: Please tag correctly the database that you are using. Please also post the error message that you are getting

Comment: first, select your DB style one

Answer (score 0):

You're using `count()` function instead of `sum()` function.
As per your requirement, the query should something similar to

```
SELECT COMPANY,SUM(VALUES) FROM TABLE2
GROUP BY  DATEPART(MONTH, Period)
```

If you want the query without group by, use direct where clause.

```
SELECT SUM(VALUES) FROM TABLE2 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, Period) = 01;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Only for MySQL, DATEPART is not available in MySQL

```
SELECT MONTH(Period) as gmonth, Period, Company, SUM(Values) FROM `TABLE 2`
GROUP BY  MONTH(Period);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question with the Oracle tag as well, here you go: `TO_CHAR` function with the `'mm'` format mask fetches month from the date (01 for January, 02 for February, etc.). As there's an aggregate function (`count`) involved, you have to `GROUP BY` column that isn't aggregated. (As far as I can tell, that is valid for any other database.)

```
SQL> with test (period, company) as
  2    (select date '2018-01-01', 'A' from dual union all
  3     select date '2018-01-02', 'A' from dual union all
  4     select date '2018-02-04', 'A' from dual union all
  5     select date '2018-02-05', 'B' from dual union all
  6     select date '2018-03-06', 'B' from dual union all
  7     select date '2018-04-07', 'C' from dual union all
  8     select date '2018-05-08', 'A' from dual
  9    )
 10  select to_char(period, 'mm') month, count(*)
 11  from test
 12  group by to_char(period, 'mm')
 13  order by 1;

MO   COUNT(*)
-- ----------
01          2
02          2
03          1
04          1
05          1

SQL>
```